# Problema con sql query en modo only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql

Tengo el siguiente problema. Una tabla tb_cs de la que pongo un ejemplo teorico:

```
id idcontrato idproducto cant 
1      C1        IDP1     2
2      C1        IDP2     3 
3      C1        IDP1     2
4      C1        IDP3     1
```

el problema es contar la sum de cant de un IDP pero tengo que ordenarlo por el ID.

esta es mi consulta:

```
select idproducto idp, sum(cant) cidp 
from tb_cs where idcontrato=:idc 
group by idproducto 
order by id
```

con esa consulta me da error por la activacion de only_full_group_by, pero si incluyo ID en el select
ej:

```
select id, idproducto idp, sum(cant) cidp from tb_cs 
where idcontrato=:idc 
group by idproducto, id 
order by id
```

me repite el mismo IDP y eso no puede ser.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda. Ya he googleado cantidad y he hecho cualquier cantidad de cambios.

Comment: porque ordenas por id? id deberia ser un numero interno de la db, que logica usas para usarlo como clausula de orden?

Comment: es que en el diseño original, el ID (AUTO_I) me deteremina el orden en que entran los insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo no entendía bien esto del `only_full_group_by` ... creo haberlo entendido mejor gracias [a esta respuesta en SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20074634/5587982).

Cuando se usa `GROUP BY`, lo que hace el manejador es que toma varias filas y las convierte en una fila. Debido a esto, **tiene que saber qué hacer con todas las filas combinadas donde hay diferentes valores para algunas columnas**.

Esta es la razón por la que tenemos dos opciones para cada campo que deseamos seleccionar: o incluirlo en la cláusula `GROUP BY`, o usarlo en una función agregada para que el sistema sepa cómo se desea combinar el campo.

Por ejemplo, en tu caso:

```
id   |  idcontrato   |  idproducto   |  cant 
---------------------------------------------
1           C1              IDP1         2
2           C1              IDP2         3 
3           C1              IDP1         2
4           C1              IDP3         1
```

Si dices `GROUP BY idproducto`, ¿cómo sabrá qué `id` mostrar en el resultado en el caso de las filas `1` y `3`? Entonces, puedes incluir `id` en el `GROUP BY`, lo que dará como resultado las mismas cuatro filas que tienes ahora. O bien, usar una función agregada para mostrar cómo manejar los `id`. Por ejemplo, `MAX(id)`.

Sabiendo eso, podríamos introducir ese elemento de orden que no quieres en los resultados finales en una sub-consulta, en la cual sí le diremos lo que queremos hacer con el valor `id`, de hecho, le diremos **que se quede con el valor más pequeño de los `id` que encuentre : `MIN(id)`** y al mismo tiempo ordenaremos por ese valor.

La consulta sería esta:

<kbd>**[VER DEMO](http://rextester.com/MZLYVB6489)**</kbd>

```
SELECT 
    t1.idp, 
    t1.cant 
FROM 
    ( 
        SELECT  MIN(id) id, 
                idproducto idp,  
                SUM(cant) cant
        FROM tb_cs
        WHERE idcontrato='C1' 
        GROUP BY idp
        ORDER BY id
     ) t1
;
```

Y el resultado:

```
idp   | cant
-----------
IDP1  |  4
IDP2  |  3
IDP3  |  1
IDX8  |  1
```

#### Post-Data

Si quieres evitar el uso de sub-consultas, puedes escribir tu instrucción de este modo:

```
SELECT 
    idproducto,
    SUM(cant) AS cant
FROM 
    tb_cs
WHERE 
    idcontrato='C1' 
GROUP BY 
    idproducto
ORDER BY 
    MIN(id);
```

Comment: Gracias....!!!! Justo lo que estaba buscando hace dias.